# Why do my checklist get reset when I move the card it is in horizontal?

Tags: trello

Ok I have multiple checklists withing several different cards. When I move them from in progress to review stage all the lists in the card have been reset. Is there a way to reverse it? is there a way to move the cards so they don't get reset? I'm frustrated because now i will need to spend a couple of hours going through the list and double checking when we have done and what still needs to be complete.

Can anyone help!

Comment: Sounds like a bug - your probably best off contacting Trello support: https://trello.com/help